# Efficiently re-computing area under ROC when one label changes

Tags: algorithm

Say that you have a list of scores with binary labels (for simplicity, assume no ties), and that we've used the labels to compute the area under the associated receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve. For a set of n scores, this calculation is straightforward to do in O(n log n) time -- you simply sort the list, then traverse the list in sorted order, keeping a running total of the number of positively labeled examples you've seen so far.  Every time you see a negative label, you add the number of positives, and at the end you divide the resulting sum by the product of the number of positives times the number of negatives.

Now, having done that calculation, say that someone comes along and flips exactly one label (from positive to negative or vice versa).  The scores themselves do not change, so you don't need to re-sort.  It's straightforward to calculate the new area under the curve (AUC) in O(n) time by re-traversing the sorted list.  My question is, is it possible to compute the new AUC in something better than O(n)?  I.e., do I have to re-traverse the entire sorted list to get the new AUC?

I think I can do the re-calculation in O(1) time by  storing a count, at each position in the ranked list, to the number of positives and negatives above this position.  But I am going to need to repeatedly calculate the AUC as more labels get flipped.  And I think that if I rely on those stored values, then updating them for the next time will be O(n).

Comment: I'd tend to agree. The position of all points in the curve that come after the changed label will be different, so I wouldn't see how to improve below O(n) here. But I'll be happy to be proven wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to compute AUC in O(log(n)). You need two sets of scores, one for positives and one for negatives, that provide the following operations:

1. Querying the number of items with higher (or lower) score than a given value (score of the label being flipped).
2. Inserting and removing the elements.

Knowing the number of positives above/below given position lets you update AUC efficiently as you already mentioned. After that you have to remove the item from the set of positives/negatives and insert to negatives/positives, respectively.
Balanced search trees can do both operations in O(log(n)).

Furthermore, actual values of scores do not matter, only position is relevant. This leads to very simple and efficient implementation using binary indexed tree. See http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees for explanation.
Also, you don't really need to maintain two sets. Since you already know the total number of positives and negatives above given position, single set is enough.